# What is the opposite of wireframe?

Tags: antonyms, computing

In computer graphics, wireframe means literally just a frame of lines(wires), meant to represent some other 3D shape(such as a cube). What is the opposite of wireframe, as in colored in normally like a solid object?

Comment: just what you called it, "solid object".

Comment: 'rendered image'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite of a **wireframe** object is, as you've already noted, a **solid** object.

One might also refer to a **matcap** or **textured** object - these would normally be understood as solid although in reality they might still show the wireframe drawn over the solid face.

Another alternative (in between solid and wireframe) is a **transparent** object. In 3D usage that implies partial transparency of some/all of the faces allowing you to see areas of the model that wouldn't necessarily be in view in **solid** mode.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16339/how-to-apply-matcap-materials-for-sculpting-in-blender-2-71

Comment: As tchrist has said: 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.' 'Solid object' and 'transparent object' may well be the correct answers, but need to be accompanied by authoritative references.

Answer (score 0):

*Surfaces* or *solids*.  Wireframe uses *only curves* (2D or 3D) to indirectly model (represent, suggest, render) surfaces and solids.

Representations that display surfaces and solids are contrasted with wireframe models, but even such representations are sometimes just based on wireframe models (i.e., only curves are used to define or suggest the surfaces and solids). IOW, the representation is just rendering, with no underlying surfacic or solid mathematical model.

Mathematical representations of surfaces and solids are a better contrast with wireframe: the surfaces and solids are directly modeled by mathematical or algorithmic objects.